# Celery: Prioirity of remote machines

Tags: python, celery

I have the same celery worker running on two machines. But i want that one machine grabs more tasks because it has more system resources. Is that possible?

So i have machine 1 and machine 2 and on both of them there is running a calculuationTasks.py with simple code:

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('calculuationTasks',
             broker='???',
             backend='???',
             result_backend='???')
app.conf.update({
    'task_routes': {
        'calculuationTasks.add': {'queue': 'calculation'},
    }
})

app.conf.update(task_track_started=True)#,result_extended=True)

@app.task(bind=True, soft_time_limit=100000)
def add(self, number):
    return number*2
```

In my code i now execute:

```
add.delay(10)
```

On both machines i previoulsy start the celery worker of course with:

```
celery -A calculationTasks worker --loglevel=info --concurrency 8 --queues=caclulcation -n machine1@%h

celery -A calculationTasks worker --loglevel=info --concurrency 8 --queues=caclulcation -n machine2@%h
```

And now i want that machine 2 gets more of those tasks.

Comment: Adapt the concurrency values?

Comment: If machine 2 has more resources, it should complete the tasks faster... and therefore pull more of them. Avoid the temptation to optimise until you are actually measuring resource utilisation.

Comment: so there is now way to specify with the delay call from with remote machine the tasks sould be executed?

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as increasing the `concurrency` setting on machine 2 to 10: `celery -A calculationTasks worker --loglevel=info --concurrency 10 --queues=caclulcation -n machine2@%h`

Each celery worker can have different settings. You already use this - you specified different names.